# How can I build something like Amazon S3 in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, storage

I am looking to code a file storage application in perl similar to amazon s3. I already have a amazon s3 clone that I found online called parkplace but its in ruby and is old also isn't built for high loads. I am not really sure what modules and programs I should use so id like some help picking them out. My requirements are listed below (yes I know there are lots but I could start simple then add more once I get it going):

- Easy API implementation for client side apps. (maybe REST (?)
- Centralized database server for the USERDB (maybe PostgreSQL (?).
- Logging of all connections, bandwidth used, well pretty much everything to a centralized server (maybe PostgreSQL again (?).
- Easy server side configuration (config file(s) stored on the servers).
- Web based control panel for admin(s) and user(s) to show logs. (could work just running queries from the databases)
- Fast
- High Uptime
- Low memory usage
- Some sort of load distribution/load balancer (maybe a dns based or pound or perlbal or something else (?).
- Maybe a cache of some sort (memcached or parlbal or something else (?).

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking to code it, why are you talking about clones? I don't see anything special in your requirements. What's the question?

Comment: I really don't know why I mentioned the clone, but my question pretty much is what would you recommend for modules and or programs for my requirements.

Comment: Are you asking for advice about setting up the service or advice about programming an interface to such a service? What is your question?

Comment: Advice about programming such a service to do what I want. For example for the USERDB, I could use PostgreSQL and DBIx::PgLink from cpan but id like advice of what would be better to use than PostgreSQL and the module I mentioned if there is even something better to use.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `MogileFS` may help?

- [MogileFS homepage](http://danga.com/mogilefs/)
- [Contributing to MogileFS](http://contributing.appspot.com/mogilefs)
- [Google code repo](http://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/)  (*however note sixapart repo in contributing link*).

Also there was a [recent discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mogile/browse_frm/thread/9f216274654181ad) about MogileFS performance on the [Google Groups / Mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/mogile) which maybe of interest to you.

/I3az/

Comment: Thanks, But I was already planning on using MogileFS for the storage.

Comment: Good stuff.   Two great mind think a like ;-)   Or fools never differ :(

Comment: As MogileFS isn't mentioned anywhere here uptil now then this answer is very useful as a reference for future seekers.

Comment: I am rethinking about using mogilefs for this, because it seems to be for a few servers with not a whole lot of storage. I am planing to be running 400+TB per rack. But now I am not sure what to use for storage.

Answer (score 0):

here I found a ruby impl

https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3

hope that helps

mike

Answer (score 0):

I have created a super simple server, see the put routine in Photo::Librarian::Server.pm it supports the s3cmd put of a file, nothing more for now. 
https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/photo-librarian-server

https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/photo-librarian-server/commit/837706542e57fbbed21549cd9e59257669d0220c